# If you embed an extremely thin magnetic strip in superconducting block do supercurrents form around the strip?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, superconductivity

Given a superconducting block (lets assume type 1) in grey below and a very thin magnetic strip with a simple magnetic dipole structure (in blue below) inserted into the block. If we were to cool the block below its superconducting transition temperature would there be permanent super currents coiling around the strip? I would expect the immediate (maybe few atom vicinity) of the strip to be non superconducting (unless the magnetic strip was very weak) and the superconductor would have eddy currents responding to the strip but its not necessarily obvious how these currents should be distributed to me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If we replace the super thin magnet with a flux tube passing through a “non superconducting region” then the answer seems like a yes per this: [quora answer](https://www.quora.com/If-I-have-a-superconductor-that-is-flux-pinned-to-a-magnet-and-I-rapidly-move-a-piece-of-metal-between-the-two-will-the-pinning-effect-discontinue)

Where the answerer Tristan Walker states: “ So the flux forms into a ‘filament’ called a fluxoid which is ‘cocooned’ by a cylinder of current around itself”

The magnetic strip itself is non superconducting so we might expect similar behavior here as long as the magnet isn’t too strong and breaks superconductivity around it.