# Would flux tubes be prevented from passing through a sufficiently thick superinsulating layer?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, superconductivity, vortex, insulators

Suppose you have a  type-2 superconducting cube with a thick [superinsulating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superinsulator)  layer passing through the middle of the cube; visualized below with (grey superconducting mass, violet superinsulator in the middle):

[image]

Now suppose you have a flux tube connecting the front face $A$ to the back face $B$ that lies entirely on one side of the superinsulating layer. Visualized below with same color scheme (flux tube in blue):

[image]

It's been explained that flux tubes can move (preferring paths through defects) as the magnetic field generating them within the superconductor itself changes/moves. Someone on physics.stackexchange had popularized [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kKMoQZ1JKo) which demonstrates the motion of the tubes.

Now If there is a superinsulating layer, one would expect that tubes perhaps cannot pass through the layer and would just stay stuck on one side of the layer. The explanation for this is that the tube itself has a [cylinder of supercurrent surrounding it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/794012/if-you-embed-an-extremely-thin-magnetic-strip-in-superconducting-block-do-superc) and that supercurrent cannot move into the superinsulating layer so naively one might expect that the entire tube would just not pass through and hang around, creating lots of mechanical resistance/friction to being pushed (relative to what a flux tube normally creates) until the surroundings heat up sufficiently to destroy the supercurrent when trying to move the magnetic field relative to the superconductor in a direction against the superinsulating layer.

Is this a fair way to think about this conceptually?